# Build debug vs release on Android

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a Samsung tablet.
My app was developed based on a native library.
The native library has a release build.

I use Android Studio to do development. I use debug-x86 as build variant and the app can run correctly on the device.

1. I am curious why the app can run correctly even the native code is built as release?
2. Which build variant should I use.
3. If I use release build variant, can the performance be improved compared with debug variant?

Many thanks.

YL

Answer (score 3):

1. You can (should) use the release version of a library in your project. And it is not related to your project build variant because you are not using the library source code, but compiled output.
2. About your project/app, you should use `Debug` variant for debugging purposes and `Release` variant when you already want to release your app, say, in a market like Play Store.
3. Yes, the performance in release mode is higher than debug, as many extra logs are not run anymore when the app is running. This is particularly sensible when the project is a large one with many hundreds of classes and libraries.

Answer (score 2):

• When creating an app, you work (develop the app) using a debug build.

• When the app is ready, you deploy (publish to the stores) the release build.

• The release build is always faster and optimized, as it doesn't hold any debug information.

• The debug build contains extra information to help you develop your app, therefore it can be slower than the release build. In addition, can have a larger size, and of course, you don't want to deploy debug information to your users, not to mention that makes it much simpler to reverse engineer.

• The build type of the library you use for your app is unrelated. These should always be deployed as a release, although the developer of the library you use can give you both, a debug and a release one to help you out in development. If they give you both variants, the same logic applies as explained above, and Android Studio will pick up the correct one based on your current build type.